# React Router can't find action for nested route's form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

React router can't find action of nested route.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mb4u8c?file=src%2FApp.js)

In short,

1. In `index.js` I used the first route like this. I used `path="/*"` to render `<App />`. There is dummy action to check which action is called.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      path="/*"
      element={<App />}

      action={async ({ params, request }) => {
        let formData = await request.formData();
        console.log('/* action->', formData);
      }}

      }}
    ></Route>
  )
);
```

2. In `app.js`, I defined nested route. When user access `"/userActionData"`, I will render `<SignUp />` example. I also defined action for form inside the `<SignUp />` Component(`userActionData.js`). I expected that when the form submits, action of route(/useActionData) is called but, `react-router` run action in route (/*).

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {/* <div style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}>
        <Outlet />
      </div> */}

      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={<App_List />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/useActionData"
            element={<SignUp />}
            action={SignUpAction}
            loader={SighUpLoader}
          />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotImplemented />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I think using the `path="/*"` is the problem, but I can't find how to make `react-router` find the correct action (which defined in `app.js`, route `path="/useActionData"`).

Answer (score 0):

The new Data APIs necessarily need to be passed ***at-the-time*** when creating the Data Router. It's because at compile/transpile-time the new Data Router can't possibly know what descendent routes it will be rendering at run-time. All the app routes would need to be moved into the configuration.

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      element={<App />} // * Note
      action={async ({ params, request }) => {
        let formData = await request.formData();
        console.log('/* action->', formData);
      }}
    >
      <Route element={<Layout />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<App_List />} />
        <Route
          path="/useActionData"
          element={<SignUp />}
          action={SignUpAction}
          loader={SighUpLoader}
        />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotImplemented />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
);
```

**** Note:** Ensure that `App` is rendering the `Outlet` component so the nested routes can render their `element` into it.*